# Cannot access locally hosted web server from any browser

Tags: windows, localhost, webserver

I'm running a react app dev server with `npm start` and I see it's hosted:
[image]

Then I'm trying to access it from two different browsers on the same machine and there is no response: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

System: Windows 10.
I tried to change the port and to clean the routing table and also to create another clean application (using create-react-app) and run it, but it doesn't work.

Moreover yesterday it worked fine.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Welcome To StackOverflow, Please add the image content as code to the post

Comment: You say you "are running a react app dev server". Do you mean is it an node server? are you using express? Please add the package.json to your question and also please don't add images to the question but rather add code or text as it makes it easier for future references (images might brake, you cannot search over images' text, etc). Also, include a part of the server code that you think is relevant to the situation or at least where it is configured and initialised.

Comment: Yes, it's an express server. But the server itself is not a problem because I've created a new app by "create-react-app" and also another one (using http-server) results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved.
I needed to turn off my ESET antyvirus firewall. It was blocking from accessing any localhost.